# resizing UINavigationController layout problem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, resize

I'm trying to add a ADBannerView inside my extended UINavigationController.
When the banner loads I re-size the view like this:

```
CGRect contentFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
banner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50; 
bannerHeight = banner.bounds.size.height;

self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, 
                                  (self.view.bounds.origin.y), 
                                  self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                                  contentFrame.size.height - (bannerHeight));
```

but the UIView is partially hided under the navigation bar: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZQfw.jpg)

Any idea what is wrong?

thanks

[1]:

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, 
                              (self.view.bounds.origin.y)+(bannerHeight), 
                              self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                              contentFrame.size.height - (bannerHeight));
```